# How to load an image from my FXML file by simply dragging the image from my PC to the SceneBuilder?

Tags: java, image, javafx

I want to load an **Image** that is on my FXML file by simply dragging the **Image** file from my Pictures folder to the SceneBuilder. However, the **Image** does not show in my program.

Here is my `scene.fxml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="collage.Controller">
    <ImageView fitHeight="413.0" fitWidth="608.0" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="-4.0">
        <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Pictures/Pictures/84273.jpg"/>
    </ImageView>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is my main method:

```
package collage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/layout/scene.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have a dedicated `Controller` class for my FXML file, however, I am unsure of what to initialize inside the `Controller` class in order for my image to show.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Are you saying that you want to run your program and **then** drag/drop an image from your computer into SceneBuilder and have your program update in real time? That is impossible since the FXML is compiled when you build your application and can't be updated on-the-fly.

Comment: @Zephyr I'm trying to make an FXML scene on SceneBuilder which shows a simple image from my PC. That image was simply dragged from my Pictures folder to the SceneBuilder. However, the image does not show when I try to execute the program, even though the image can be seen on the actual SceneBuilder app.

Comment: See the [eden coding guide to JavaFX resources](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/).

Comment: @jewelsea Will do, thanks for the info!